# Parsing JSONArray with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

How can I parse that json array ,which is string format with using Swift  ? I was doing by hand like removing brackets and splitting text by commas etc. But algorithm goes wrong if any of array elements has comma inside like ("DEF1,23") . So is there any predefined library from Apple to do that ?

Note : I saw some solutions in stackoverflow but that functions takes inputs which is NSData formatted so, I need string implementation of that parsing functions.

```
var jsonstring : String = "["ABC123","DEF1,23","ASD54,21"]"
```

Comment: Convert the string to NSData and use NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let str: NSString = /* json string */
var error: NSError?
if let data = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSArray {
    println(data)
}
```